# Javascript - Select next object in array of objects based on a specifc object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filter, filtering, indexof

I have the following:

```
    currentPhase: {
      endDate: "2030-12-31T09:00:00.000Z"
      startDate: "2021-06-26T11:00:00.000Z"
      status: "ended"
     }
```

And an object with more objects:

```
    phases: {
        ended: { 
          startDate: "2021-06-26T11:00:00.000Z", 
          endDate: "2030-12-31T09:00:00.000Z"},

        openingSoon: { 
          startDate: "1899-12-31T21:00:00.000Z", 
          endDate: "2021-06-17T09:25:31.000Z" },  
  ​​    
        playing: { 
          startDate: "2021-06-15T21:00:00.000Z", 
          endDate: "2021-08-30T21:00:00.000Z" },   
 ​   
        readyToPlay: { 
          startDate: "2021-06-13T11:00:00.000Z", 
          endDate: "2021-06-15T21:00:00.000Z" },  
  
        registrationsOpen: { 
          startDate: "2021-06-07T19:00:00.000Z", 
          endDate: "2021-06-12T17:00:00.000Z" },  
 
        resultsPending: { 
          startDate: "2021-08-30T21:00:00.000Z", 
          endDate: "2021-06-26T11:00:00.000Z" },    
        }
```

*CurrentPhase* will change quite often, and whenever *CurrentPhase* changes, I need to select the next phase from *phases* based on the currentPhase.

What I have tried is to filter phases(which does not work as it is not an array) based on the endDate of currentPhase, what I could also do is phases[currentPhase.status], but how do I retrieve the current index of phases[currentPhase.status] in order to select the NEXT object after phases[currentPhase.status] in order to display it's starting date?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have the objects inside an array and just store the current index in another variable.
I've also added made it so that it loops around, if that's what you need, just remove the ternaries and use `Math.max` and `Math.min` instead.

```js
var index = 0;

function next() {
  index = ++index >= phases.length ? 0 : index;
  console.log(phases[index].status);
}

function prev() {
  index = --index <= 0 ? phases.length - 1 : index;
  console.log(phases[index].status);
}

var phases = [{
  startDate: "2021-06-26T11:00:00.000Z",
  endDate: "2030-12-31T09:00:00.000Z",
  status: "ended"
}, {
  startDate: "1899-12-31T21:00:00.000Z",
  endDate: "2021-06-17T09:25:31.000Z",
  status: "openingSoon"
}, {
  startDate: "2021-06-15T21:00:00.000Z",
  endDate: "2021-08-30T21:00:00.000Z",
  status: "playing"
}, {
  startDate: "2021-06-13T11:00:00.000Z",
  endDate: "2021-06-15T21:00:00.000Z",
  status: "readyToPlay"
}, {
  startDate: "2021-06-07T19:00:00.000Z",
  endDate: "2021-06-12T17:00:00.000Z",
  status: "registrationsOpen"
}, {
  startDate: "2021-08-30T21:00:00.000Z",
  endDate: "2021-06-26T11:00:00.000Z",
  status: "resultsPending"
}];
```

```html
<button onclick="prev()">Previous</button>
<button onclick="next()">Next</button>
```

---

**Edit**
Fast ES6 way to convert the original object to an array:

```
Object.entries(phases).map(([key, value]) => ({ ...value, status: key }));
```

IE compatible approach:

```
Object.keys(phases).map(function (key) {
    var oldObject = {}, newObject = {};
    for (var subKey in oldObject) newObject[subKey] = oldObject[subKey];
    newObject.status = key;
    return newObject;
});
```

Comment: I'm sorry, having a hard time right now, I am retrieving all the data(phases, currentPhase) from an API and it comes as such, how would I be able to convert it as in your method? I have tried multiple things, entries, keys, values, none seem to work properly and get me the same results.

Comment: @ParticleEffect If you don't care about IE support you can use `Object.entries(phases).map(([key, value]) => ({ ...value, status: key }));` to convert it to that form. (I've also updated the answer)

Answer (score 0):

```
const phasesStatuses = Object.keys(phases); // Get array of phases statuses
const currentPhaseIndex = phasesStatuses.indexOf(currentPhase.status); // get index of current phase


const nextPhaseStatus = phasesStatuses[currentPhaseIndex + 1]; // get next phase status, which will be the key of next phase in phases array
const nextPhase = phasesStatuses[nextPhaseStatus];
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const currentPhase = {
    endDate: "2030-12-31T09:00:00.000Z",
    startDate: "2021-06-26T11:00:00.000Z",
    status: "ended",
}

const phases = {
    ended: {
        startDate: "2021-06-26T11:00:00.000Z",
        endDate: "2030-12-31T09:00:00.000Z" },
    openingSoon: {
        startDate: "1899-12-31T21:00:00.000Z",
        endDate: "2021-06-17T09:25:31.000Z" },
    playing: {
        startDate: "2021-06-15T21:00:00.000Z",
        endDate: "2021-08-30T21:00:00.000Z" },
    readyToPlay: {
        startDate: "2021-06-13T11:00:00.000Z",
        endDate: "2021-06-15T21:00:00.000Z" },

    registrationsOpen: {
        startDate: "2021-06-07T19:00:00.000Z",
        endDate: "2021-06-12T17:00:00.000Z" },

    resultsPending: {
        startDate: "2021-08-30T21:00:00.000Z",
        endDate: "2021-06-26T11:00:00.000Z" },
}

const phasesList = Object.keys(phases)
const currentPhaseIndex = phasesList.indexOf(currentPhase.status)
const nextPhase = currentPhaseIndex === phasesList.length - 1 ? phasesList[0] : phasesList[currentPhaseIndex + 1]

console.log(nextPhase)
```